# How to print unicode from a generator expression in python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Create a list from generator expression:

```
V = [('\\u26' + str(x)) for x  in range(63,70)]
```

First issue: if you try to use just `"\u" + str(...)` it gives a decoder error right away. Seems like it tries to decode immediately upon seeing the `\u` instead of when a full chunk is ready. I am trying to work around that with double backslash.

Second, that creates something promising but still cannot actually print them as unicode to console:

```
>>> print([v[0:] for v in V])
['\\u2663', '\\u2664', '\\u2665', .....]
>>> print(V[0])    
\u2663
```

What I would expect to see is a list of symbols that look identical to when using commands like `'\u0123'` such as:

```
>>> print('\u2663')
♣
```

Any way to do that from a generated list? Or is there a better way to print them instead of the `'\u0123'` format?

This is NOT what I want.  I want to see the actual symbols drawn, not the Unicode values:

```
>>> print(['{}'.format(v[0:]) for v in V])
['\\u2663', '\\u2664', '\\u2665', '\\u2666', '\\u2667', '\\u2668', '\\u2669']
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr Be aware that `\u` is followed by hex digits.

Comment: What are you trying to do? All Python 3 strings are Unicode, same as Javascript, Java, C# strings. `A` is a Unicode character. Unicode is a character-to-byte encoding, not a set of escape sequences.

Comment: `print([u"{}".format(v[0:]) for v in V])`

Comment: And even the escape sequences are *not* part of the string. An escape sequence is a way to specify a character without actually typing that character. When you type `'\u0041'` the actual string is just `A`. If you want to convert numbers to a corresponding character use `chr`, ie `[chr(x) for x  in range(2663,2670)]`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki that would be too easy :-)   I want to see the actual symbols not codes, when calling `print`.   Edit: it seems you can't post images in comments, I will add it in the main Q.

Comment: @peterkarasev it's not needed to begin with. Just `chr` with the *correct* values will work. The strings you create don't contain Unicode escape sequenses, they contain 5 characters, \, u,2,6` etc. Escape sequences are replaced by the actual character by the interpreter, so when the interpreter sees \\ it sees an escaped \ followed by `u`

Comment: @peterkarasev why such complicated code instead of just using the correct range? If you want to convert from hex to decimal use `int(16,x)`. There's no need for string concatenations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode is a character to bytes encoding, not escape sequences. Python 3 strings are Unicode. To return the character that corresponds to a Unicode code point use [chr](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#chr) :

> **chr(i)**
> Return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is the integer i. For example, chr(97) returns the string 'a', while chr(8364) returns the string '€'. This is the inverse of ord().
>
> The valid range for the argument is from 0 through 1,114,111 (0x10FFFF in base 16). ValueError will be raised if i is outside that range.

To generate the characters between 2663 and 2670:

```
>>> [chr(x) for x  in range(2663,2670)]
['੧', '੨', '੩', '੪', '੫', '੬', '੭']
```

Escape sequences use hexadecimal notation though. 0x2663 is 9827 in decimal, and 0x2670 becomes 9840.

```
>>> [chr(x) for x  in range(9827,9840)]
['♣', '♤', '♥', '♦', '♧', '♨', '♩', '♪', '♫', '♬', '♭', '♮', '♯']
```

You can use also use hex numeric literals:

```
>>> [chr(x) for x  in range(0x2663,0x2670)]
['♣', '♤', '♥', '♦', '♧', '♨', '♩', '♪', '♫', '♬', '♭', '♮', '♯']
```

or, to use exactly the same logic as the question

```
>>> [chr(0x2600 + x) for x  in range(0x63,0x70)]
['♣', '♤', '♥', '♦', '♧', '♨', '♩', '♪', '♫', '♬', '♭', '♮', '♯']
```

The reason the original code doesn't work is that escape sequences are used to represent a single character in a string when we can't or don't want to type the character itself. The interpreter or compiler replaces them with the corresponding character immediatelly. The string `\\u26` is an escaped `\` followed by `u`, `2` and `6`:

```
>>> len('\\u26')
4
```

Comment: awesome. yeah in this case I just neeeded `int('..', base=16)` added too: Great explanation that fundamentally it is not an "escape sequence mapping".

Comment: This works for me, thanks:

`print([chr(int('26'+str(x),base=16)) for x in range(63,70)])`

Comment: I posted the code *and* the results. BTW I just found out you can use hex notation in integers, there's no need for conversion. You can use `range(0x2663,0x2670)`